# Is the $\mathbb R^2$-valued random variable $(X,X)$ absolutely continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

> Let $X$ be a standard Gaussian random variable. Is the $\mathbb R^2$-valued random variable $(X,X)$ absolutely continuous ?

I don't understand the question here. Now $X$ has density $\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})$

I have to find out if the cumulative distribution function is continuous right ?, but how is cdf defined in more dimensional case ?

Does it have to do something with Radon-Nikodym theorem, marginal distributions ?

Comment: How does your book define absolute continuity for two-dimensional distributions?

Comment: In particular, even in one dimension, being absolutely continuous is not the same as having a continuous cdf.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge 1. We don't have a book just the notes from the professor 2. In this notes there's no definition of absolutely continuity. I find this condition in the internet

Comment: Then this is a question you should be asking your professor. We can't know what proof you should give if we don't know what definitions to use.

Comment: @NateEldredge This is not a homework exercise, so you can use any definition

Comment: Your professor is asking you questions based on notions they never defined? Really? Where do they do that?

Comment: @Did We only had discrete distributions and absolutely continuous distributions, with a density(where the term appears). We had measure theory and integration course with the same professor, there we defined it but this is not really helpful for this question.

Comment: Oh. So finally you do have a definition. Then why say otherwise? Bring it up! (Unrelated: the density of X cannot be what you wrote, the thing is not a density.)